# YouTube PHP API - Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, youtube

I've got a working website, which uses youtube api. Everything was fine but today I noticed I get error while using this api:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 403 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error><domain>yt:quota</domain><code>too_many_recent_calls</code></error></errors>' in /root/public_html/grabandrun.com/public/ZendGdata/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php:700 Stack trace: #0 /root/public_html/grabandrun.com/public/ZendGdata/library/Zend/Gdata.php(221): Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('GET', 'http://gdata.yo...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL) #1 /root/public_html/grabandrun.com/public/ZendGdata/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php(861): Zend_Gdata->performHttpRequest('GET', 'http://gdata.yo...', Array) #2 /root/public_html/grabandrun.com/public/ZendGdata/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php(754): Zend_Gdata_App->get('http://gdata.yo...', NULL) #3 /root/public_html/grabandrun.com/public/ZendGdata/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php(205): Zend_Gdata_App->importUrl('http://gdata.yo...', 'Zend_Gdata_YouT...', NULL) #4 /root/public_html/grabandrun.com/public/ZendGdata/library/Zend/Gdata.php( in /root/public_html/grabandrun.com/public/ZendGdata/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php on line 700
```

my code looks somehow like this:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Uri_Http');
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$query = $yt->newVideoQuery();
$query->setQuery($searchTerms);
$query->setStartIndex($index2);
$query->setMaxResults(10);
$query->setOrderBy($order);

$videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($query);

foreach ($videoFeed as $videoEntry) {
    $videoThumbnails = $videoEntry->mediaGroup->thumbnail[0]->url;
    $title = $videoEntry->mediaGroup->title;
    $vidId = $videoEntry->getVideoId();
    $vidDescription = $videoEntry->mediaGroup->description;
    $duration = $videoEntry->mediaGroup->duration->seconds;
    $rating = round($videoEntry->rating->average,1)." out of 5";
    echo "info...";
}
```

Funny thing is that it sometime works and sometime does not... I don't really know why, any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: And <error><domain> **yt:quota** </domain><code> **too_many_recent_calls** </code></error> tells you nothing, huh? :)

Comment: It does but how do I lower recent calls or how do I manage to make it work? :)... Or the only way for me is to limit people visiting? Seems quite stupid to me for a youtube api. Am I using anything wrong? Calling the api too much? Anything else? :)...

Comment: The only thing you can do is to catch these exceptions and tell users to try again later when they occur; and also locally cache results for some frequently used search terms. Maybe there is some way to increase quota for your app, but I'm not sure about that, try googling...

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm not sure they'll let me to increase the limit since I'm downloading their videos :)... I'll just inform users then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments, I just had to limit the access and lower the calls. Thanks Slava.